# Is it correct and natural to ask "what is something count?" when you want to know how many something there is?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Would you tell me if it is correct and natural to ask *what is something count?* when you want to know how many something there is. For example:

> What's the pallet **count** and what are their sizes?

By that I mean how many pallets are there. I've heard people say it a few times, but is that a natural way to ask the question?

Comment: That's ordinary usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is correct.

It can be used in situations in which the speaker wants to make some such distinction as between reality and accounting. So, asking "What is the pallet count?" is asking about the number written down in the records. This is distinct from asking what the true number of pallets is.

Sigh. I have been doing a lot of quality assurance lately. It makes me cynical.

Answer (score 2):

I feel I'd limit this to situation in which an actual physical count had taken place.

Nearly always I'd just use "How many pallets are there?"